# Jquery selectors for specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select ONLY `<h2>` element in the specific `<div>`, but NOT to select all others `<h2>` in the body. The access to the `h2` should pass through my "myclass1".

```
<div class = "myclass1></div>

<div class = "myclass2">
 <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
```

But I understood it will select all `h2` elements in the page. How can I transform the code to select this specific h2 element?

Comment: show the html code you're selecting from

Comment: You should add to your selector an identifier `id`..

Comment: Give your <h2> a unique class or id. ie <h2 class="my_h2">

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: `element in the specific <div>` meaning 1 div only or all div with this class?

Comment: Your sample seems to work as you require given that there's only 1 `h2` element. It would be better if you showed a sample which contains both the elements you *do* and *do not* want to select so we can figure out the required selector logic

Comment: We need the complete HTML code you use. All the comments and replies are fine, but we need to see the entire HTML code.

Comment: The thing is I use this popover library somewhere else in the project so I want to avoid unnecessary changes for the other places. And everywhere the construction is the same. opoover div and h2.

Answer (score 1):

The selector seems correct.

It will select all `h2` elements who have any parent with a class of `myclass`.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$(".myclass h2:contains('Title')")
```

Comment: Can I do something like this.

>`$('.popover h3').attr('id', 'titleID').popover().removeClass('popover-title');`

Answer (score -1):

There's several ways to achieve that and several selectors to use..

You could identify your target tag or the container targeted, for example using class `target` :

```js
$('.target h2').addClass('highlight');
```

```css
.highlight{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "myclass">
  <h2>Title</h2>
</div>

<div class = "myclass">
  <h2>Title</h2>
</div>

<div class = "myclass target">
  <h2>Title</h2>
</div>

<div class = "myclass">
  <h2>Title</h2>
</div>

<div class = "myclass">
  <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
```

Example using identifier `id="target"` :

```js
$('#target h2').addClass('highlight');
```

```css
.highlight{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "myclass">
  <h2>Title</h2>
</div>

<div class = "myclass">
  <h2>Title</h2>
</div>

<div class = "myclass" id='target'>
  <h2>Title</h2>
</div>

<div class = "myclass">
  <h2>Title</h2>
</div>

<div class = "myclass">
  <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue is I can not add Id manually. So I added it with $().attr('id', 'myID')

Comment: So please give us the full relevant HTML code so we can help.